# CiviEvent, marking a pending attendee as Registered does not send email?

Tags: civievent, email

CiviCRM 5.67.1, WordPress 6.4.1. We have an event created that is semi-private, in that it's not a Public event, is a Members-Only event, but because we are allowing registrations based on membership tier, each request has to be approved. So far so good, although I do wish there was a way for the system to verify that the person signing up is an allowed membership level natively.

So Require Participant Approval is checked. There's also a waitlist, but that's not relevant here.

I as the admin don't get an email when someone is waiting approval, which is one thing. Could probably create a scheduled task or report to let me know, but given how many emails are sent at other stages, curious why this email isn't sent?

If I just move everyone's status from Awaiting Approval to Registered, they don't get any email notification either. If I move it to Pending from Approval, they get an email saying they need to click on a link (which most have, but many haven't, and quite frankly, this does seem like an unnecessary extra step here).

We will be sending out periodic event updates to all registered contacts so they'll know they are registered then -- but if they aren't registered, they would not know to expect an email that they never get, and my main issue to resolve here is making sure people who make it to Registered are notified they made it to Registered with an easy way to manage that (yes, Allow Self Service... is checked).

Am I missing some simple setting somewhere on this?

Thank you.

Michael

Comment: I don't know if it's supposed to send emails or not, but another option is set up some civirules to send an email when participant status changes.

Comment: Interesting idea, but a quick look here doesn't look like simply sending an email when a condition is met (status changed from Awaiting Approval to Registered or status changed from Pending from Approval to Registered, for instance) is an available out-of-the-box action. This can be used to notify someone of a new approval request, sure, but doesn't look like it can notify the contact who just got registered.

Comment: The participant is the default recipient. On the action you just fill out from email address and message template.

Comment: There is a condition available for 'Compare Old Participant Status to New Participant Status' which may be worth looking at?